# SRV record behavior when client specifies a port

Tags: srv-record

Since I was not able to find and answer, I'm using Stackoverflow for the first time.

When I set up a SRV record like this: `_test._tcp.example.com. 86400 IN SRV 0 5 1337 testserver.example.com.`, I'm assuming that when I request *testserver.example.com*, it will send me to *example.com:1337*.
But what will happen when i go to *testserver.example.com:420* ? Will it send me to *example.com:1337*, *example.com:420* or something completely different?

I could just try it and see what happens, but that would require spending some money, which I want to avoid until I'm sure it will be useful.

Thanks for you time reading and hopefully answering this question.